# Redirect to https htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have the following htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

The problem is that I get the following error when checking HTTPS setup "http.domain redirects to https.domain through a redirect chain. This hurts your rankings"

Comment: This error comes where?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [webmasters.se]

Comment: Not sure about that. It has an element of webmasters, but it is a programming issue how the chain is being created, so I don't think this is off-topic.

Comment: You must have some other rules in place for there to be a chain. Please post all your redirects.